# Twincat/BSD on Raspberry PI?

Tags: raspberry-pi, twincat

Is it possible or did someone manage to get **TwinCAT BSD** running on a **raspberry pi**?
I heard that ARM devices are not yet supported by this OS, but on the beckhoff website it is stated:

Quote: "FreeBSD supports both 32 and 64 bit platforms and makes scalable systems possible with ARM CPUs extending up to powerful Xeon CPUs"
Source: https://www.beckhoff.com/en-us/products/ipc/software-and-tools/twincat-bsd/

If not, would it be possible via a virtual machine running on the raspberry pi?
Or does it really need to run on top of a x86 or x64 CPU?

PS: I know that it's possible to get it running on VirtualBox on Windows, but **I am specifically asking about a solution with a raspberry pi**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TcBSD/TwinCat is currently only available for x86 (32 bit) and x64 (64 bit) Intel and officially only supported on their industrial/embedded hardware.

FreeBSD, however is supported on Raspberry PI:
[Raspberry Pi 3/4](https://download.freebsd.org/releases/arm64/aarch64/ISO-IMAGES/13.1/)

I've never tried, but you should be able to install FreeBSD on a [Rock Pi X](https://wiki.radxa.com/RockpiX) which is compatible with many Raspberry Pi Hats but is Intel based. The Rock Pi X also runs Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

On the question of whether or not you could run TC/BSD on unsupported hardware:
You’d likely need to modify it and it would depend on FreeBSD working on the RockPi X first.

Comment: Okay, as far as I understand, a linux based operating system does not automatically mean it supports all hardware with ARM processors - seems I got confused here.

Installing FreeBSD won't be a big issue, but for TwinCAT the TwinCAT Runtime is need, wich I won't be able to install on any OS other than Windows or get it preinstalled with a TcBSD system.

I have spoken to an Beckhoff employe, and he of course said TcBSD won't be supportet on the Raspberry Pi. 
The two alternatives are installing CODEYSY, on which TwinCAT is based on, or buying a low end PLC from Beckhoff, like the CX7000.